# How to record and replay macros in Android?

Tags: automation

Is there a way to record macros and replay them? I want to record real touchscreen and keyboard presses I make when I'm using an app, and be able to "replay" them later to repeat the same actions.

Something like [iMacro](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), but for Android instead of Firefox.

Comment: You would need root for this with a 100% certainty, and the development for root apps isn't like that of regular apps (due to cash flow), with a few notable exceptions (like TitaniumBackup, which still works a little bit without root I guess). I would say that there's almost certainly nothing like this out there ready made, although it's obviously possible for anyone with the programming skills.

Comment: How to implement it effectively? The way I can currently imagine is just ptrace'ing Android's system process, temporarily overriding data coming from /dev/input/event* file descriptors.

Comment: [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en) can do it.